# Sylius: API-Call with OAuth-Token always redirects to "connect"-Route

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, sylius

I tried out the sylius API with oauth on a complete new sylius project(0.17.0). But on every simple api-call with valid access-token, the response is always 301 redirect to the route "/connect".

## What i did:

#### 1. Creating the API CLient:

```
php app/console sylius:oauth-server:create-client --grant-type="password"
```

Output:

> "A new client with public id
>   3ogfp09nbikg440ssg4ss84k4ww4wgw00gc8w4kksskggoocso, secret
>   4vawhwsg4hwk8gocgk08ogkcgwgswo0k0og0w0cgkk8g8cgsg4 has been added"

#### 2.  Get the Token:

```
curl http://www.domain.dev/oauth/v2/token \
    -d "client_id"=3ogfp09nbikg440ssg4ss84k4ww4wgw00gc8w4kksskggoocso \
    -d "client_secret"=4vawhwsg4hwk8gocgk08ogkcgwgswo0k0og0w0cgkk8g8cgsg4 \
    -d "grant_type"=password \
    -d "username"=myvalidusername \
    -d "password"=myvalidpassword
```

Everything works fine:

```
{    "access_token":"MDUxZWQ4M2U0ZmJmNTEyZTdkNDRlMjkxY2E3MTE2ZTM0ZDVkZjMwZjEyNjRiOWZlMTdkMmJkOTA1ZmFiNGFmMA",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "scope":null,
   "refresh_token":"NWNmZjkwNTM1MWNiMDU5OWVhN2NjOGQ5N2U5MGFiYTkxYWVlYmNiNDBkNTJlNzJjZjE1MzI1MjI5MzI2YTc3Nw"
}
```

#### 3. Making a simple API-Call using the authorization with token as http header:

curl http://www.domain.dev/api/users/ -H "Authorization: Bearer MDUxZWQ4M2U0ZmJmNTEyZTdkNDRlMjkxY2E3MTE2ZTM0ZDVkZjMwZjEyNjRiOWZlMTdkMmJkOTA1ZmFiNGFmMA"

Output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.domain.dev/connect" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://www.domain.dev/connect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://www.domain.dev/connect">http://www.domain.dev/connect</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i ran into the same and opened an issue at github: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4707